Question: Is the function $e^{iz^2} $ holomorphic?
I'm trying to determine whether the function $ f(z) = e^{iz^2}$ is holomorphic.
From my understanding, a function is holomorphic if it is complex differentiable at every point in its domain, which involves verifying the differentiability and ensuring that the Cauchy-Riemann equations are satisfied.

Given the function $ f(z) = e^{iz^2} $, can someone help me verify if it is holomorphic by checking its differentiability and the Cauchy-Riemann equations?

If my function do not verify the Cauchy-Riemann equations can i say that is not holomorphic?


To calculate the Cauchy-Riemann equations for the function $ f(z) = e^{iz^2} $, we express it in terms of its real and imaginary parts:
$$
f(z) = e^{iz^2} = e^{i(x^2 - y^2 + 2ixy)} = e^{-y^2 + ix^2} \cdot e^{2ixy}.
$$
The real part $ u(x, y) $ and imaginary part $ v(x, y) $ are:
$$
u(x, y) = e^{-y^2} \cos(x^2),
$$
$$
v(x, y) = e^{-y^2} \sin(x^2).
$$
The partial derivatives are:
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = -2xe^{-y^2} \sin(x^2), \quad \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = -2ye^{-y^2} \cos(x^2),
$$
$$
\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = 2xe^{-y^2} \cos(x^2), \quad \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} = -2ye^{-y^2} \sin(x^2).
$$
Verifying the Cauchy-Riemann equations:
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}, \quad \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = -\frac{\partial v}{\partial x},
$$
Is this right?
How do i check if a function is differentiable?

It is easier than this. Show that a composition of holomorphic functions is holomorphic. Now you only need to show that $e^z$ is holomorphic and that $iz^2$ is holomorphic.

Do you know that a continuous (real) function is differentiable if its partial derivatives are continuous?

@geetha290krm Read OP carefully. What does the second paragraph signify?

Your calculation of the real and imaginary parts of f is wrong in at least two steps.

In particular, $a(b+c) \ne ab + c$, and $e^{2ixy} \ne 1$.
